# any assist in understanding some for-loops? (java)

Tags: java, for-loop

Ok, so I got this program that prints out a pyramid!

Heres the code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("How many rows?: ");
    int amountOfRows = keyboard.nextInt();

    int maxIndentation = amountOfRows + 2;

    for(int row = 0; row < amountOfRows; row++){
      int antallx = 2*row;

      // indent
      for(int column = 0; column < maxIndentation - antallx / 2; column++){
        System.out.print(" ");
      }

      // prints a row
      System.out.print("d");
      for(int kolonne = 0; kolonne < antallx; kolonne++){
        System.out.print("0");
      }
      System.out.println("b");
    }
  }
```

Question: I know a bit about how for-loops etc work, but what I am wondering is if someone could please explain what the for-loops does in this program and also a bit about the choose of the variables, specially when it comes to adding and or multiplying them with a number (that part is confusing me a lot, how they decide if they want to +2 the variables like with amountOfRow, and multiply with 2 like for antallx)?, and im also wondering big time on the second for loop, how do they come up with dividing by 2 etc? any help would be much appreciated! thanks in advance! :)

Comment: It would probably be instructive to go through a small case (say, 3 rows) with pencil and paper, and work out what the various values of the variables would be.

Comment: hmm, I tried ths, but I didnt seem to find a pattern. tbh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at that application, and it is doing it in a way in order to teach you about both loops and mathematics.  Specifically look at your example and focus on the following lines

- `column < maxIndentation - antallx / 2`
- What is `maxIndentation - antallx / 2` equal to? Recall `antallx = 2 * row`

Then I would test your pyramid program with different inputs (1, 2, 3, ...) to see how each of them changes the final output of the program.

Here is a commented version of your program that I hope shows you how this program works.  You can also use an online IDE to see the code compiled, see [here](http://ideone.com/QU5U53)

```
// This program will output the following type of pyramid
//   db
//  d00b
public static void main(String[] args){
    //a scanner is a tool for reading input from a stream
    //in this case, you are reading from the user input window (console)
    //Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    //asks users how many rows of a pyramid they want
    System.out.print("How many rows?: ");
    //int amountOfRows = keyboard.nextInt();

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {           
        printPyramid(i);
        System.out.println("\n\n"); //this line essentially prints a newline x3
    }
}

public static void printPyramid(int amountOfRows)
{
   int maxIndentation = amountOfRows + 2;


    for(int row = 0; row < amountOfRows; row++){
        int antallx = 2*row;

        for(int column = 0; column < maxIndentation - antallx / 2; column++){
            System.out.print("|");
            //I changed " " to "|" so you can see what this for loop is printing
        }

        System.out.print("d");
        for(int kolonne = 0; kolonne < antallx; kolonne++){
            System.out.print("0");
        }
        System.out.println("b");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use substitution.  If `antallx = 2 * row`, then `antallx / 2` would really be what?

Comment: Yep!  Therefore `for(int column = 0; column < maxIndentation - antallx / 2; column++)` would actually just be `for(int column = 0; column < maxIndentation - row; column++)`.  You also know that `row` increases by 1 with each for loop.  Therefore, the number of column indents decreases by one each loop!

Answer (score 0):

Its all about logic.
1) Just like what you said, It prints a pyramid
2) maxIndention and antallx variables are just used for spacing. The programmer just only wants that logic to be applied into his program. You can do another different logic if you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you have 2 for loop one inside the other.

The first loop: Row =0; is the starting point, so your loop with start at zero.

Then it check for your condition, and if it is true row it will run thr codr below the forloop and  will iincremented by 1 so the next row is now 1. It will do this as long as your , condition is true.

The second loop: will do the same thing however when row = 0; column will start at zero and execute until the condiction becomes false, when row =1 the condiction column will again start at zero and execute until the condiction is false. It will do this until the first loop becomes false.

Really life example

You have 20 dollar and you used 10 dollar for a burger, after couple hour you feel hungry again and you buy other burger the same price. You only do that as long as you have more than 10 dollars. If you have less thecondition becomes false.